# Inequality between the rank of matrix and the $\ell_1$-norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, matrix-rank, matrix-analysis

Let $B=[b_{ij}]\in M_n(\mathbb C)$ and $b_j$ denote the $j$th column of $B$.

> **Problem:** Prove that $$\text{rank} B\geq\sum_{b_j \neq 0} \frac{|b_{jj}|}{\| b_j\|_1}$$
> where $\|b_j\|_1 = \sum_{j=1}^n |b_j|.$

I don't have any idea or approach on how to show this inequality. Any help and hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $\| b_i\|_1 = \sum_{j=1}^n |b_{ij}|$ ?

Comment: Nope its the $\ell_1$ norm on the columns of $B$.

Comment: So $\| b_i\|_1$ is the $\ell^1$ norm of the $i$-th column of $b$ ? (Denoting $b_i$ for the $i$-th column is not standard notation, you should make it explicit in your question)

Comment: My mistake. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

**Sketch of proof:** Find an invertible, diagonal matrix $D$ such that all columns of the matrix $M = BD$ have $1$-norm $0$ or $1$ and the diagonal entries of $M$ are all non-negative. Observe that the rank of $M$ is equal to the rank of $B$.

On the other hand, note that $\|M\|_1 \leq 1$, which implies that all eigenvalues of $M$ have magnitude at most $1$. Conclude that
$$
|\operatorname{tr}(M)| \leq \operatorname{rank}(M).
$$

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong : $\| M\|_1$ is the operator norm associated with the $\ell^1$ norm, ie : $$\| M \|_1 = \sup_j \sum_i |M_{ij}| $$

Comment: That’s exactly right

Comment: That's a very nice proof

Comment: Sorry, can you enlighten me for a bit. Especially the diagonal matrix $D$ what kind of diagonal matrix is $D$

Comment: @Tokita Try writing out the product $BD$ for $n=2,3$ and see if you can figure it out what $D$ should be in these cases. It might help to look at specific matrices $B$ and solve for the necessary entries of $D$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Another question for the last conclusion. The step I didn't get is the part where number of nonzero eigenvalues of $M\leq$ rank $M.$ Sorry for my dumbness there are many steps that I can't fill out.

Comment: Use the fact that the trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues along with the triangle inequality. The number of non-zero eigenvalues that a matrix has is at most equal to its rank.